# 3D vision with accessory display

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, 3d-vision

I have a single 3D monitor paired to an NVIDIA SLI. I was given a second monitor that is not 3D. Can I use it to make non-game apps bigger, but still have 3D on the first screen?

Basically I want "3D surround + accessory display" except instead of 3+1 I have 1+1 screens. Games would play only on the first screen, but other apps could use the second too.

I'm not sure if this is possible, or how I would go about doing it. If it's not, I'll leave the new monitor in the package.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by other apps? Do you mean you want a  game running on the 3D monitor and the (for example) calculator running on your second screen? If so, this can be done, but, you'll have to CTRL+TAB out of the game (if it allows and doesn't crash as some games can be finiky about this). Plus, when running games, they quite often change system settings (such as resolution)

Comment: @DaveRook It doesn't have to be simultaneous. As long as I can make it usable when I'm not playing a game.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand (sorry). What you're describing is how we use multiple monitors? I quite often have Photoshop in monitor 1, Outlook in monitor 2 and FireFox on my third monitor. Or is the question about how the 3D element is affected?

Comment: @DaveRook Yes, the 3D part. Having two different refresh rates and how that will affect gaming.